# Problem with my onClick(). updates data of the wrong index in the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

Hi I have a table with heading patientinfo and location. Under Heading location, each row has 5 buttons and the buttons have `patientLocationSelect()` `onClick`. the 5th button is different to others because that button reveals more buttons  when clicked on a popover. On the popover there are further button that have `patientLocationSelect()` `onClick`.

The onClick on first 4 buttons works as expected. the `patientLocationSelect()` takes in the id of locationButton that was clicked and patient index, then on state it updates the location of the correct patient in array.

**The problem**

The 5th button reveals further buttons however `patientLocationSelect()` always picks up the last patient in the array. In this case it always Macho, and update only his location. I can't figure out why.

```
 patientInfo: [
                {room: 1, name: 'John',  location: ''},
                {room: 2, name: 'Shawn', location: ''},
                {room: 3, name: 'Brave', location: ''},
                {room: 4, name: 'Macho', location: ''},
              ]
```

```
   patientLocationSelect = (e, data, index) => {

        const { id } = e.target;

        this.setState({
            patientInfo: this.state.patientInfo.map((patient, i) => {
                if (i=== index){
                    return {...patient, locationInfo: id};
                }
                return patient;
            })
        });
    }
```

```
  const popoverButtons = [
        "Dinning Room",
        "Garden",
        "Shower",
        "Activity Room",
        "Toilet", 
    ];


 locationButtons : ['Bed', 'Corridor', 'TV', 'Lounge'],


<tbody>
            {patientInfo.map((patient, index) =>
                <tr>
                    <td>{patient.room}</td>
                    <td>{patient.name}</td>
                    <td className="location-btns">
                        {locationButtons.map((location, i) =>
                            <Button
                                 key={i}
                                onClick={(e) => patientLocationSelect(e, patient, index)}
                                id={location}
                            >
                                {location}

                            </Button>
                        )}

                        <Button id="Other" onClick={showPopOver}>Other</Button>

                        <Overlay
                            show={show}
                            target={target}
                            placement="left"
                         >

                            <Popover id="popover-contained">

                                {
                                    popoverButtons.map((item, i)=> 
                                        <Button
                                            key={i}
                                            onClick={(e) => patientLocationSelect(e, patient, index)}
                                            id={item}
                                        >
                                            {item}
                                        </Button>
                                    )
                                }
                            </Popover>
                        </Overlay>

                    </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Overlay component is rendered when you click on Other button, right? Which means the patient info is rendered completely. It means map function on patientInfo is done. So it always returns the last patient info.

To solve it you could save the patient info in state on click on Other button as below:

```
<Button
 id="Other"
 onClick={() => {
    this.setState({ activePatient: patient, activeIndex: index });
    showPopOver();
 }}
>
    Other
</Button>
```

And then on click on Popover buttons do as below:

```
onClick={(e) => patientLocationSelect(e, this.state.activePatient, this.state.activeIndex)}
```

Hope this would solve your problem

Comment: I've done bit more of debugging and it seems that all the popovers are shown and stacked over on top. So when i click on the other buttons, it is the last popover hence why it updates the last patient. I need to figure out how to only open popover individually for individual patient

Comment: can you create a code sandbox/code pen to demonstrate the issue